# Matlab optimization - getting multiple points to evaluate / roundabout parallelization

Tags: matlab, optimization

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the actual function to be optimized, f(x), takes a single input x.

I want to use MATLAB to optimize f(x), but f(x) can not be evaluated within MATLAB. f(x) can only be evaluated in some other environment. What I have in MATLAB instead, is another function that takes a list of x values to evaluate, get's the other environment to evaluate it in a roundabout way, then returns the corresponding values of f(x) after some time. I want MATLAB optimizer to come up with, for example, 16 values of x to be evaluated at a time, receive the corresponding 16 values at a time, and come up with the next 16 values to be evaluated.

I do not want MATLAB itself to do anything in parallel, I just want the optimizer to work in "batches". What would be the best way of going about this? Is there a name for it?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/vectorized-surrogate-optimization.html